# Can composer.phar be deployed with the code?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using Composer for a small project. I've pushed `composer.json` and `composer.lock` to Git, and put the `vendor/` folder into `.gitignore`, so I can install the dependencies at the server on deploy time.

Can I push `composer.phar` to the Git repo or should I install a new copy for the server? Not sure if the installation process is machine-dependant.

Comment: @mudasobwa Why? If you don't commit the .lock you wont always get the exact same version as your local install, especially if you don't specify very exact versions in your composer.json. I always version my .lock file.

Comment: @mudasobwa uhm, composer.lock is specifically designed to be used as a dependency locker, and in fact it's recommended in the composer docs to version it for that very reason: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: @mudasobwa I suggest you delete your wrong comment, because the composer.lock file actually MUST be committed to ensure any later deployment will use the same versions. `composer install` with the lock file will install exactly the versions that are being recorded. And doing so is very quick. `composer install` without the lockfile is the same as `composer update` - and this is not what you want if you deploy to production, because you likely don't want to grab the newest updates that you never tested with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a lot easier to install composer.phar manually on each server where you need it, as it will prompt to be updated every 30 days, and you don't want to be forever updating the content of your repo for a composer update.

Composer is a tool to help you with your deployments, so it should not be a part of your deployments

Comment: It seems to me that all the same, composer.phar file in the git would be useful.
Imagine a situation if your project uses old unsupported libraries and their installation is not possible with the latest version of composer. You need to specify this in the documentation or save the composer version with which your project will be 100% built.
I faced this issue when I upgraded composer to version 2 and couldn't run composer update due to the presence of the zendframework packages in my composer.json.
This file is not large enough to not add it to the git.

Answer (score 1):

I personally store `composer.phar` in git for some PHP projects, usually in the project root directory.

This has the advantage that you can easily enforce the same composer version across multiple team members / computers, which can reduce the differences in `composer.lock` files, especially after running `composer update`. This may not be very standard, but I often document this in the project README.